# Mosquitto bridge how to clear retained message on local broker which are cleared in the remote broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, bridge, emq

I have set up a MQTT bridge using a mosquitto broker.
Config:

```
connection bridge-01
address url:1883
try_private true
cleansession true
topic posttopic1 in 0 "" topic1
remote_username username
remote_password password
```

Everything works fine, including retained messages. Messages that are published to the remote broker with the retain flag set will be published to the local broker with the retain flag as well. However when a retained message in the remote broker is cleared. By sending an empty message to a topic with the retain flag. The message is cleared in the remote broker but it is not cleared in the local broker. Why is that and how do I enable that feature?

The local broker is mosquitto version 1.6.10 and it is an MQTT v3.1.1 broker.

Comment: I can not reproduce this with mosquitto 2.0.15. Any specific reason you can't upgrade (1.6.10 May 2020 is very old and there have been a lot of security updates since)

Comment: Also is it mosquitto on both ends and if so are they both running 1.6.10?

Comment: @hardillb We are using Yocto dunfell to build our linux image. I think we need to upgrade to an other version of yocto to upgrade the mosquitto version, which is a bit of a hassle. The remote broker is a emqx MQTT broker.

Comment: Ok the test was between 2 mosquitto brokers, the important part will be if the null payload is published over the bridge, which would be down to emqx in this case. You need to test that to determine the root cause

Comment: I have narrowed it down to that there seems to be an issue with the emqx broker, or at least some kind issue between the emqx and mosquitto brokers. Thank you for your help.